# Remove quotation marks from invocation parameter

Tags: cmd

I want to process files in a subroutine by passing a filename and adding path + extension

This is what I have coded

```
echo %0 %1 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "input=P:\Convert\%1.ts"
echo.Process "!input!"
```

If the filename contains no blanks I dont need quotation marks. But if it includes blanks, then I must enclose the parameter in quotation marks to pass it to the subroutine. Here is what I get:

```
sample test
Process "P:\Convert\test.ts"    <-- this is OK

sample "test file"
Process "P:\Convert\"test file".ts"   <-- NOT OK
```

How do I get rid of these quotation marks ?

Comment: `%~1` removes surrounding quotes. (see `call /?` for some other interesting modifiers)